Convert openAi functions to gemini function calling
When having a projet that deal multiple Generative AI provider, I must have a quick way to "translate" the Function Calling Tools from one provider to another.
Having a object with tools to be used with openAi SDK, how to convert it to Gemini Tools?
Sample tool list:
import { ChatCompletionTool } from 'openai/src/resources/chat/completions';

// Tools in the OpenAi Schema 

const openAiTools: ChatCompletionTool[] = [
  {
    type: 'function',
    function: {
      name: 'saveLead',
      description: 'Save lead information',
      parameters: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          name: {
            type: 'string',
            description: 'Lead name',
          },
          phone: {
            type: 'string',
          },
          email: {
            type: 'string',
            description: 'Valid email RFC 5322',
          },
        },
        required: ['name', 'phone', 'email'],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    type: 'function',
    function: {
      name: 'escalateToHumanAgent',
      description: 'Escalate to human agent',
      parameters: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          reason: {
            type: 'string',
            description: 'Reason for escalating to human agent',
          },
        },
        required: ['reason'],
      },
    },
  },
];


I wrote this code that convert a OpenAi function list to the Gemini defaults, with TypeScript.
// Having openAiTools already declared 

const convertToolsToGemini = (
  tools: ChatCompletionTool[],
): FunctionDeclarationsTool[] => {
  return tools.map((tool) => {
    const { type, properties, required } = tool.function.parameters;
    return {
      functionDeclarations: [
        {
          name: tool.function.name,
          description: tool.function.description,
          parameters: {
            type: type.toUpperCase() as FunctionDeclarationSchemaType,
            properties: Object.fromEntries(
              Object.entries(properties).map(([key, value]) => {
                const prop = value as { type: string; description?: string };
                return [
                  key,
                  {
                    type: prop.type.toUpperCase() as FunctionDeclarationSchemaType,
                    description: prop.description,
                  },
                ];
              }),
            ),
            required: required as string[],
          },
        },
      ],
    };
  });
};

// Call conversion method
const geminiTools = convertToolsToGemini(openAiTools);

// Ready to use with Gemini SDK



Code gist

